# how we can filter data in dataframe in R

Tags: r, time-series

```
           f1      f2
3     11/2/16   56.25
5     11/3/16   56.25
7     11/4/16  111.00
10    12/5/16   13.00
16    11/8/16   35.00
19    11/9/16  415.21
22   11/10/16  280.00
23   12/10/16  817.00
24   10/11/16  830.00
25   11/11/16  644.00
28   11/12/16   90.00
31     2/1/17  250.00
33     3/1/17   45.00
34     3/1/17  184.00
35     4/1/17  578.16
36     4/1/17  160.00
37     5/1/17   21.00
39     6/1/17  352.00
41     6/1/17 2089.00
44     7/1/17  855.00
45     8/1/17  488.00
46     8/1/17  573.00
47     8/1/17  654.00
50     9/1/17 1995.00
55    11/1/17  115.00
56    11/1/17 2147.00
57    12/1/17   74.00
59    12/1/17 1431.00
60     1/2/17   50.00
62     2/2/17  657.00
67     5/2/17  629.00
71     6/2/17   23.00
75     8/2/17  350.00
77     8/2/17 1449.00
79     9/2/17  364.00
80     9/2/17 1185.00
85    11/2/17  405.00
86    11/2/17 4725.00
87    12/2/17   50.00
88    12/2/17  202.00
89    12/2/17 2377.00
90     1/3/17  500.00
91     2/3/17  600.00
93     3/3/17   60.00
94     3/3/17   14.00
```

Having above dataset name dat.filtered.This data have to be converted in time series data.
Trying this code giving error:

```
library(xts)
xts.sample <- xts(dat.filtered$f2, order.by = as.Date(dat.filtered$f1, "%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Giving this error:

Error in xts(dat.filtered$f2, order.by = as.Date(dat.filtered$f1, "%d/%m/%Y")) : 
      'order.by' cannot contain 'NA', 'NaN', or 'Inf'

how can this error be removed.

Comment: You don't need to use `$` inside  `subset`; but it should still filter entries by `f2 > 0`. Stating *"but did'nt get the desired result"* is not very specific. What didn't work? Either way, I'm giving a sample solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Filter
dat.filtered <- subset(dat, f2 > 0)

# Convert to time-series
library(xts);
xts.sample <- xts(dat.filtered$f2, order.by = as.Date(dat.filtered$f1, "%d/%m/%Y"))
```

---

### Sample data

```
dat <- read.table(text =
    "                              f1              f2
1                         11/1/16               0
2                         12/1/16               0
3                         11/2/16           56.25
4                         12/2/16               0
5                         11/3/16           56.25
6                         12/3/16               0
7                         11/4/16             111
8                         12/4/16               0
9                         11/5/16               0
10                        12/5/16              13
11                        11/6/16               0
12                        12/6/16               0
13                        11/7/16               0
14                        12/7/16               0
15                        10/8/16               0
16                        11/8/16              35
17                        12/8/16               0
18                        10/9/16               0
19                        11/9/16          415.21
20                        12/9/16               0
21                       10/10/16               0
22                       11/10/16             280
23                       12/10/16             817
24                       10/11/16             830
25                       11/11/16             644
26                       12/11/16               0
27                       10/12/16               0
28                       11/12/16              90
29                       12/12/16               0
30                         1/1/17               0
31                         2/1/17             250
32                         2/1/17               0
33                         3/1/17              45
34                         3/1/17             184
35                         4/1/17          578.16
36                         4/1/17             160
37                         5/1/17              21
38                         5/1/17               0
39                         6/1/17             352
40                         6/1/17               0", header = T, row.names = 1)
```

Comment: if dat dataset is data.frame how can we do it.

Comment: @Saurabh `dat` *is* a `data.frame`. Run my example. It's fully reproducible.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Maurits Evers  i want to ask if in place of text we have data.frame variable name as t then what will be the changes in it.

Comment: @Saurabh I have no idea what you're saying. *"if in place of text we have data.frame variable name as t then what will be the changes in it"* What does that mean? I'm working with the example data that *you* posted.

Comment: i was having  a dataset after that after that i taken out two columns and named as f1 and f2 .So after that i combine these columns using cbind by this following code:f1 = data$X
f2 = data$net_weight
w1 = data.frame(f1)
w2 = data.frame(f2)
t = (cbind(w1,w2))  So i want to ask that how to read data as you have read sample data above.

Comment: @Saurabh That looks like awful code, and the entire process seems completely unnecessary to me. That aside, to create a new `data.frame` named `dat` that consists of two columns `f1` and `f2` from columns `data$X` and `data$net_weight` you can do `dat <- data.frame(f1 = data$X, f2 = data$net_weight)`. Then proceed as in my solution.

Comment: giving message-    "Warning message:
In Ops.factor(f2, 0) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors"                         
 after doing dat <- data.frame(f1 = data$X, f2 = data$net_weight) and then using your solution.

Comment: @Saurabh **Always provide representative sample data**; **otherwise this is a guessing game and waste of time for people trying to help!** Clearly this has **nothing** to do with the original question that you posted. Instead the issue here is that you failed to ensure proper data types for the columns. Try  `dat <- data.frame(f1 = as.character(data$X), f2 = as.numeric(as.character(data$net_weight)))` and then my solution.

Comment: Sorry again for asking again as it will be the last question  i won't understand about it as we are converting into time series using xts giving error as: "Error in xts(dat.filtered$f2, order.by = as.Date(dat.filtered$f1, "%d/%m/%Y")) : 
  'order.by' cannot contain 'NA', 'NaN', or 'Inf' "

Comment: @Saurabh Well did you check `dat.filtered$f1`? Again, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49707181/edit) your question, don't post code in comments, and provide representative sample data (use `dput(data)`)!

Comment: @MauritsEvers Perhaps relevant reading: [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions); [What is a help vampire?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire).
 Don't burn out yourself ;)

Comment: @Henrik Thanks & good advice! Appreciate the nudge;-)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advice you to use the dplyr package for filtering. The functions in dplyr work very intuitive.
For converting the date variable, use the package lubridate.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

dat_cleaned <- dat %>%
                filter(f2 > 0
                #filter() function from dplyr
dat_cleaned$f1 <- dmy(dat_cleaned$f1)
#dmy() function from lubridate
```

Comment: Given OP's obvious struggle with base R functions and basic R objects, I'm not sure if advising OP to use a different library is necessarily going to make things easier.  Also, it seems that OP is after time-series data; `dmy` produces `Date`/`POSIXct`/`POSIXlt` objects; that's not the same thing.

Comment: According to my opinion there are a few packages to use from start, dplyr is one of them, because the functions in dplyr are so consistent built up they are easier to work with then many base R functions. And if you have to do with data variables using lubridate is so much easier then using base R functions. Of course changing date in character format to a date format is not the same as time series analysis, but it is the first thing to do, isn't it?